# How to search a value from a column with like in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns column1 and column2, I'm trying to retrieve rows that contain in column1 value from column2.

So it should be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataset.table AS t 
WHERE t.column2 LIKE '%' t.column1 '%'   -- I know it's wrong syntax..
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few simple options:

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where column2 like '%' || column1 || '%'
```

or

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where regexp_contains(column2, column1)
```

Comment: `column2 like '%' || column1 || '%' ` that's what I'm looking for. But I get an error:  `pattern too large - compile failed` my table is also very large (about 26GB). Is there a way to get it worked?

Comment: regexp_contains does not help me because I get wrong results. e.g., it says `build=prod&pscb=c97ec7461a33550c918fe9e80024d6cc
` contains the value `1|1592377200000`. It's because of `|`, but not sure how to solve that problem

Comment: I replaced chars like | \ with \| and \\ so it works now well. thanks!